# MySql server denies access at localhost

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Working on a simple JDBC program to communicate with a MySQL server. The Eclipse Helios is reporting this error:

```
SqlException: `access is denied at localhost`.
```

I don't know if I have the wrong server's passwordor the database's password. I provide the username and password along with the URL of the server to the JDBC class driver. I created the password with `mysql_embedded.exe`.

Would it matter if I created the database with MySQL Workbench or with `mysql_embedded.exe`? Or simply a password issue?

Comment: SQL Server question you have tagged in mySQL. lol'z

Comment: Make sure you are trying to connect to the right mysql server, if you are sure your credentials are fine and you type them and database name correctly. You could have several servers installed and working.